# WSO2 API Manager - Can we limit supported OAuth2 Grant Type for an API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Refer to [WSO2AM documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-OAuthscopes), I understand that we can set the authentication type for each API to one of following values.

1. None
2. Application
3. Application User
4. Application and Application User

However, is it possible to specify that an API will support only a specific OAuth2 grant type?

For example, I want an API to *allow* only **"Authorization Code"** and **"Implicit"**, but *not allow* **"Password"** grant types.

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: Is this only for a particular API?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to specify this on per API basis ?

Comment: It seems there is no way to control this as API specific manner.

Comment: @harsha89 if it does not have to be API specific, what does it support? (per app? globally?)

Comment: It should be possible to remove it from globally by adjusting some configuration files.

Comment: I have further dig into this. It's looks like when we create a Application in Store, we are creating Service Provider, there you should be able to specify which grant types allows for the application. It should be good for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @harsha89 for the solution. This can be configured in carbon admin console under Service Providers -> Inbound Authentication Configuration -> OAuth/OpenID Configuration, then click "Edit".

[image]

[image]